# Unexpected result from unit testing CRUD methods from Service layer

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I'm trying to unit test the crud methods from my service layer, I've wrote the correct code (I think) but AssertTrue gives me the opposite result I was expecting.(java.lang.AssertionError:)

My test code looks as following:

**StudentServiceTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class StudentServiceTest {

    private static final String STUDENT_NAME = "Henkie";

    @Autowired
    private StudentServiceImpl studentService;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;


    @Test
    public void createStudent(){
        //arrange
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName(STUDENT_NAME);
        studentService.save(student);

        List<Student> students = studentService.findAll();

        assertNotNull(students);
        assertTrue("created a student" ,students.contains(student));
    }
```

**StudentService**

```
public interface StudentService {

    List<Student> findAll();

    Student save(Student student);

    Optional<Student> findById(Long id);

    void deleteById(Long id);

    Iterable<Student> findAllIteratable();      
}
```

**StudentServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;


    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(studentRepository.findAll());
    }    

    public Student save(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public Optional<Student> findById(Long id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

**StudentRepository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

After debugging it's visible the student is succesfully being made, and also added to the List. But as can be seen its saved under Student@10172 , and in the students List its being saved under Student@10482 . All the previous entries in the List are the result from previous test attempts.

[image]

Comment: Yes like @Alex mentioned, you need to add and override for `equals` and `hashCode`. I see that you are using `Lombok`, so all you need to do is to add `@Data` on top of your `Student` class and your test will succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly adding @Data on top of my Student class didnt change anything.

Comment: See https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/  (on why `@Data` on `@Entity` is probably a bad idea) and https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/ (how to write `equals` and `hashCode` for entities).

Comment: Good one @M.Deinum.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can't comment as I don't have the rep but... If you have the student, and you add it to the persisted object and you read it back and it is present in the collection. Then the only real question to ask is, do you override hash code and equals in your Student class?

Otherwise contains will look for the same Object, rather than the same representation of a student.